# Dynamic binding to dynamic elements in knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to build a binding that will allow me to change the type of an input element based on a property in my viewmodel, and bind the value of that input element to another property of my viewmodel.

I have the following fiddle showing what I am trying to accomplish: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4xXL/)

```
<div data-bind="dynamic: theType, value: 'theValue'"></div>

ko.bindingHandlers.dynamic = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var vm = valueAccessor();
        var $element = $(element);

        var choice = ko.unwrap(vm) || 'shortText';
        var bindTo = allBindings.get('value');

        if (choice === 'longText') {
            $element.html("<textarea rows='4' data-bind='value: " + bindTo + "' valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' />");
        } else {
            $element.html("<input type='text' data-bind='value: " + bindTo + "' valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' />");
        } // if

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $element.find(':input')[0]);
    }
};

var vm = {
    theValue: ko.observable(''),
    theType: ko.observable(''),
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Unfortunately, everything I have tried results in either the linkage between the element and the viewmodel being lost, or knockout complaining that I cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element. I know I can do this with templates, but I am wondering why my approach doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you,

Don

Comment: You can not have multiple  applyBindings

Comment: That's not true. Notice that the call inside the bindingHandler has the optional second parameter to limit the scope of the call. That is perfectly legal, and there are examples all over the net.

Comment: I'm curious about that second applyBindings even with the scope. If you open developer tools/firebug on your fiddle you'll see you're getting this error: "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. What I don't understand is what the first application is. If I take the line out, the update loses the data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. It turned out that all I needed to do was to add:

```
return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
```

from my init method, and knockout and I can get along just fine. See the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/X4xXL/2/